# Stripping Formatting on Contact Form 7 fields

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Is it possible to remove certain characters once the user has submitted the form? For example the user selects £10,000 and it would be stripped to 10000 when submitted and sent via email.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer

```
// define the wpcf7_posted_data callback 
function action_wpcf7_posted_data( $array ) { 

    //'amount' is the name that you gave the field in the CF7 admin.
    $amount = $array['amount'];

    if( !empty( $amount ) ){
        $array['amount'] = preg_replace('/[\£,]/', '', $array['amount']);
    }

     return $array;
}; 

add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'action_wpcf7_posted_data', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with latest CF7 (I tested with version 5.0.5). If I put a die() statement in the code at at the top (after function name), the die() never happens.